# :not(.class) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="like liked"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
$('.container .post .like:not(.liked)').on('click', function()
{
    // this gets fired even if the element has class "liked"
});
```

Why does the JS fire even when the element has the class "liked" when it should *only* fire if it has class "like"?

Comment: seems to work, see http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/y07qyh26/

Comment: @depperm Then I'm clueless because it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason for this would be the class `liked` is added dynamically. That is, after the handler has been registered on DOM ready.

**[Not working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dk6mLdck/1/)**

So, at the time the event handler is registered the div with `like` does not have `liked` class. So this event is valid and eventually fires on click.

Use event delegation to avoid this.

```
$('.container .post').on('click','.like:not(.liked)',function(){

})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dk6mLdck/2/)**

Another option would be,

```
$('.container .post .like').on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('liked')){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery not instead:

```
$('.container .post .like').not('.liked').on('click', function() {
    // this gets fired even if the element has class "liked"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.container .post .like').not('.liked').on('click', function()
{
    // this gets fired even if the element has class "liked"
});
```

Or,

```
$('.container .post .like :not(".liked")').on('click', function()
//                      ^^^ space between not selector
{
    // this gets fired even if the element has class "liked"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your selector is not in quotes.

```
$('.container .post .like:not(".liked")').on('click', function(){
// do stuff
});

you can also use the jQuery .not

$('.container .post .like').not('.liked').on('click', function(){
// do stuff
});
```

EDIT: Added a codepen.io example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJOLew